# How to call a C# DLL from console project?

Tags: c#, exception, dll

I'm having problems with my C# project. This is my scenario.

I have an external dll let's say `original.dll` and I need to wrap it so it can be used in multiple vb.net apps, so I'm making another dll to wrapp this orginal dll called `external.dll`. So while I'm developing this class library dll, I'm using a simple console project to test it, I included the references, build and test it with no problem... at least the first time, because when I try to rebuild my library and run it again it throws an exception

> #### FileNotFoundException
>
> Can't load file or assembly 'LynkLib, Version=1.0.5533.27875, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or any of it's dependencies.

I have already double checked the reference in VS, and the file on my folder. I try to restart VS and nothing.

Here is my code, but I don't know if it helps because I think is some kind of configuration issue.

#### External library

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
...

[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)] //to use also in vb.net 

namespace externalDLL{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Lynk
    {
        //...my code
    }
}
```

#### Console project to test

```
...
using externalDLL;

namespace TestLynk
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            externalDLL.Lynk l = new Lynk(); //Here the exception is triggered
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

I found that the problem is on the `original.dll`. I can't modify the code of that dll, I can only edit the `external.dll`. I decompile the original dll and I can see the following assembly info

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

// Assembly LynkLib, Version=1.0.5533.27875, Culture=neutral,      PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: E24FF563-B283-431E-9D53-71A59E4750E1
// References: System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// References: mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// References: System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// References: System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("LynkLib")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("###")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("###")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("###")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.5533.27875")]
```

On the rest of the code, I can see a lot of issues, there are many, but they say basically two things `// ISSUE: explicit constructor call` and `// ISSUE: variable of a boxed type`

I also downgraded my .NET version to 4.0 but still have problems. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the DLL target a higher version of the .NET framework than your console application referencing it?

Comment: The console application and the class library dll are on the same .NET version, that is version 4.5

Comment: "Original.dll" and "external.dll" are useless names when the error is about "LynkLib".  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.  Watch out for auto-generated version numbers like 1.0.5533.27875

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know if I'm right but the _LynkLib_ name is a reference to the Lynk class, because I don't have any class, object or file called LynkLib. The .cs file is called Lynk.cs and the class of the object that throw the exception is `Lynk`. Two more things, I don't know how to use `Fuslogvw.exe` and I also noticed the auto generated version number, because I checked my assemblyInfo.cs file I have version 1.0.0.0 for `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion`

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is when you reference dll's that are build to a different .net target or platform (x86 or 64bit) as your settings for your current project. Otherwise one of the dll's is referencing another dll which cannot be found. You can download DotPeek from JetBrains for free and install. Open the dll's with DotPeek and see which other dll's they reference.

Comment: I used `DotPeek` as you suggested and found some info that might help, check my update of the question.

Comment: Double check that both your project, the internal dll targets are targeting the same .NET framework as the external.dll. Also, you might have duplicate LinkLib dll's and the wrong one is picked up than the one you are referencing.